# What the following macro means in competitive programming?

Tags: algorithm, macros, time-complexity

I watched various tips to make my algorithm take less time on online judges. But I was stuck on the following code.

```
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
freopen(fi, "r", stdin);
freopen(fo, "w", stdout);
#else
// online submission
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about algorithm time. `freopen` allows you to redirect standard streams to your files. Some online judges always use standard input/output streams. And you must read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`. This macro allows you to write code that will read/write from/to stdin/stdout, but locally it will use your custom files for input and output data.